# Ensime version of scala different than project version

Tags: emacs, ensime

I get this warning when running `sbt ensimeConfig` on my project directory

```
You have a different version of scala for ENSIME (2.10.6) and webapp (2.11.8)
```

How can I change the version of Ensime to 2.11.8 globally?

Comment: Which versions of sbt and ensime are you using? Which version of the sbt-ensime plugin? Have you tried the oficial troubleshooting guide?

Comment: `addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "2.0.1")` It's not a bug so the troubleshooting guide wouldn't help. I'm using sbt `0.13.11`. I'm not sure what version of `ensime` I'm using, is that not derived from the sbt-ensime plugin?

Comment: First, update your sbt at least to 0.13.16. And do check troubleshooting guide, it's exactly for such cases and mentions minimum required sbt version: http://ensime.org/build_tools/sbt/#sbt-version